# tools::toTitleCase vs stringr::str_to_title: What went wrong?

Tags: r, string, title-case

I was just trying to convert this upper-cased string to title case using the recommended `tools` package but couldn't until I used `stringr::str_to_title()`. This is the exact code I used:

```
> tools::toTitleCase("TOOL 5a: ASSESSMENT TOOL FOR SOCIAL SUPPORT SERVICES")
[1] "TOOL 5a: ASSESSMENT TOOL for SOCIAL SUPPORT SERVICES"
> stringr::str_to_title("TOOL 5a: ASSESSMENT TOOL FOR SOCIAL SUPPORT SERVICES")
[1] "Tool 5a: Assessment Tool For Social Support Services"
```

What went wrong with the `tools` version?

Answer (score 2):

Explained in the documentation : `?tools::toTitleCase`

> No definition of‘title case’ is universally accepted: all agree that ‘principal’ words are capitalized and common words like ‘for’ are not, but not which words fall into each category.
>
> Generally words in all capitals are left alone:

Hence, `tools::toTitleCase` keeps capital letters as it is.

Comment: This is helpful when formatting proper names. It provides a simple easy solution.